# Why does this sqlplus connection string is not working in bash?

Tags: bash, database-connection, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to oracle db hosted on a server here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

RAW=`cat sqlTemp.sql`
IFS=";"
exit=" exit;"
for var in $RAW
do
query=$(echo $var | sed  '/^$/d')

sqlplus64 username/pwd@hostname:portnumber/servicename $query  2>> errorLog.txt
ERRORCODE=$?

if [ $ERRORCODE != 0 ]
then
  echo  "$ERRORCODE" >> "errorLog.txt"
      echo  "this query has  error- check the log file for detail"
else
  echo "SUCCESS"     
fi
done
```

If i replace connection string by

```
sqlplus64 -S username/pwd@hostname:portnumber/servicename <<ENDOFSQL
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
$query
exit;
ENDOFSQL
```

the script work.

what is wrong with the previous connection string and how to correct it ?

Comment: What does the `-S` option mean for sqlplus64?

Comment: @choroba -S helps in inhibiting(silent) the connection detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the connection string, "username/pwd@hostname:portnumber/servicename", in your two commands.  The difference is in how you try to present *the SQL commands* you want to have executed.  There are at least two important differences between the command that fails and the one that works.

- The one that works uses a here document to redirect several lines of input, including your "query" string, into the command's standard input, whereas the one that fails expands the query string among the command line arguments, which is a completely different thing.
- When the query string is presented unquoted on the command line it is subject to word splitting after it is expanded, but the same does not apply when it appears in a here document

Most likely, the `sqlplus64` command expects its SQL input to be presented on the standard input, which you already know how to do.  If it were prepared to accept SQL on the command line, then at minimum it would need to be quoted, and there would probably be a command-line option to tell it to look there for the SQL.

Comment: can u tell what i am failing to do in the first connection string itself ? the second one is not returning sql.sqlerrm

Comment: @realName, my point is that what you are failing to do in your first example is probably to make it like your second example.  That is, I think (but do not know for absolute fact) that `sqlplus64` will want to read its SQL input from its `stdin`, not from the command line.  Your second alternative accommodates that; your first does not.

Comment: @realName, to reiterate what I already said in my answer, a "here document" such as the second example uses feeds data to the command's standard input -- it is a *redirection* operator.  That's entirely different from making the same data a command-line argument, as your first example attempts to do.